# python calling function with only necessary parameters?

Tags: python

Say I have a function:

```
def omni(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
```

that always calls `func`.

However, func's parameters can be any combination of things. For example

```
def func(self):
    # omni should only pass in self

def func():
    # omni should pass in nothing

def func(foo, key='foo'):
    # omni should pass in a foo param and a key if supplied one

def func(*args, **kwargs):
    # omni should pass in everything
```

Is there any way to pass into `func` from `omni` only the necessary parameters? i.e. is the above possible?

ex.

```
def foo(m):
    pass

obj.omni(foo, m, a=1)
# this should call
foo(m)

def foo(self, **kwargs):
    pass

obj.omni(foo, m, 1, b=2)
# this should call
foo(self, b=2)
```

Comment: Why is the first parameter to omni `self`? Is it a part of a class? Will the `func` param also be a member function of that class?

Answer (score 0):

```
def omni(self=None, func=None, *args=None, **kwargs=None)
```

You should use optional arguments as above. Please look here http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html.

Comment: What does `*args=None, **kwargs=None` mean and how does it work?

Comment: `*args=None` and `**kwargs=None` is nonsense, and it raises a SyntaxError. If no other arguments are given, `args` is `()`. If no other keyword arguments are given, `kwargs` is `{}`.

Comment: @glglgl *args=None means that the argument *args has no value, if the caller of the function will not provide one.

Comment: @Vincent, sorry but I don't get you. Please look here http://docs.python.org/dev/library/constants.html and let me know where I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios I don't think that will work in conjunction with `*` resp. `**`. Did you try it?

Comment: @ChristosPaisios You point to the wrong docs. Look here: http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions `parameter_list ::= (defparameter ",")* ( "*" [parameter] ("," defparameter)* ["," "**" parameter] | "**" parameter | defparameter [","] )` There is no `defparameter` after `*` and `**`, only a `parameter`. And it wouldn't make sense at all.

Comment: @glglgl I didn't test it, because I thought that the answer to a question like this is straightforward. As far as the doc you point, I see there the use of None for the same reason.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios But not in conjunction with `*(args)` and `**(kwargs)`. You can write `def foo(a=None)`, but not `def foo(*a=None)`.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios If you don't get how formal arguments work, you should play with `def f(*args, **kwargs): print(args, kwargs)`.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds complicated.

You'd have to examine `func` and, for the case that `func` is an object, `func.__call__` as well.

A real function has a `func_defaults` and a `func_code`, the latter in turn having a `co_argcount` and a `co_flags`.

With their help you can examine

- how many parameters the functions has
- how many of them have default values and
- if `*args` / `**kwargs` is permitted.